# Does `Signature.init()` rewrite persistent memory?

Tags: applet, smartcard, javacard, eeprom

A few quotes from Java Card API 2.2.1:

`Signature` class description:

> A tear or card reset event resets an initialized Signature object to
>   the state it was in when previously initialized via a call to init().
>   For algorithms which support keys with transient key data sets, such
>   as DES, triple DES, AES, and Korean SEED the Signature object key
>   becomes uninitialized on clear events associated with the Key object
>   used to initialize the Signature object.

`Signature.init(...)` description:

> For optimal performance, when the theKey parameter is a transient key,
>   the implementation should, whenever possible, use transient space for
>   internal storage.

Does it mean that there are algorithms which require rewriting persistent memory each time `Signature.init(...)` is called? If yes, is there any reason for this unpleasant behaviour?

I am asking this question, because I am facing a strange behaviour in my applet. It computes ECDSA signature. After approximately 100 000 signatures the card (J2E145 by NXP) seems broken (I cannot select the applet anymore). Persistent memory damage might be the reason, because I call `Signature.init(...)` each time I receive the input data. Could the `Signature.init(...)` be the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: While only superficially acquainted with the Java smartcard variant, I'm not convinced, that Signature.init() is the culprit. You seem to do signatures, so you are using the private key, which may have an error as well as an usage counter attached. 100k write accesses is the order of magnitude you can expect for write cycles, so currently *something* seems to be written for each signature, which could be one of those counters or any other java variable you assign to during each signature.

Comment: @guidot I did some experiments: ECDSA `Signature` stays initialized after card reset. I think it is a proof `init` writes something into the persistent memory.

Comment: If I remember correctly (at least some) NXP cards change their ATR on eeprom error -- check the manuals...Good luck!

Comment: @vojta Is 100K really a problem? There is no need to re-init if you've already loaded the correct key, you could simply store the reference to the `Signature`. Compare the keys (by reference) before the init or keep multiple `Signature` instances instead if 100K is indeed a problem.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have already done that, so my problem is more or less solved. However, I still don’t understand why ECDSA writes into EEPROM. Is there any reason for that? All the computation could be performed in RAM as well, couldn’t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Signature.init()` store the reference to the key object in a persistent memory. But, I believe that the API must be implemented with a feature of "wear leveling" which should maintain the endurance of EEPROM in such scenarios.

I suggest you to come to a conclusion after checking the behavior of `Cipher.init()`, if the card continues its similar behavior or not.